# Php "" and 0 return same value

Tags: php

```
$page_now=array_search($id, $user_id);

if($page_now==""){return TURE;}
else{return FALSE}//include [0]index
```

I have an `array_search`, if it can't find the match it will return `""`,

However I have problem on `[0]` index

if the search index return 0 which is 1st one from array.

if statement `$page_now==""` & `$page_now==0` both are return TURE

Try this

```
$var=0;

if($var!=""){echo "have value in var";}else{echo "no value in var";}
```

I want it return have value even it is 0

Comment: `array_search` returns the key for needle if it is found in the `$user_id` array, `FALSE` otherwise.

Comment: Perhaps time to learn about comparisons with a loosely-typed language - http://www.php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php and http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

Comment: The [manual page for array_search](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) explicitly mentions this – so next time please read up on stuff like this before asking.

Comment: I take it this is a typo `if($page_now==""){return TURE;}` if not, it should be `if($page_now==""){return TRUE;}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a documented behavior:

http://php.net/array_search

http://php.net/manual/en/types.comparisons.php

http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php

> Warning
>
> This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a
>   non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on
>   Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the
>   return value of this function.

Also make sure you are aware about this:

> strict
>
> If the third parameter strict is set to TRUE then the
>   array_search() function will search for identical elements in the
>   haystack. This means it will also check the types of the needle in the
>   haystack, and objects must be the same instance.

You should use strict comparison operator `===` if you don't want to fall into dark abyss of PHP weak-types comparisons:

```
php > var_dump(0 == "0afca13435"); // oops, password's hash check went wrong :)
bool(true)

php > var_dump(0 == false);
bool(true)

BUT:
php > var_dump(false == "0afca13435");
bool(false)
// Uh, oh :) that's because int and string comparison will cast string to int,
// and in php string->int cast will return either 0 or any numeric prefix the
// string contain; bool and string comparison will cast string to bool, and 
// numeric prefix is no longer an issue
----------

php > var_dump(false == "");
bool(true)

php > var_dump(0 == "");
bool(true)
// WTF! :)
```

And with strict:

```
php > var_dump(0 === "0afca13435");
bool(false)
// ahh, much better
```

Answer (score 2):

The function array_search() returns false if it can't find the match. So you should use strict comparison operator `===` and compare it with `false`:

```
if($page_now===false) {
    return true;
}
else {
    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this (the empty checks if the variable is empty (""(empty string), 0, false, null etc ) is counted as empty (and will trigger this)
your code is now not checking if something is empty you only check if it isn't "" and null etc. will be triggered as not empty.

```
if(empty($page_now)){
    return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
```

if it is allowed to be 0 you can use this

```
if(empty($page_now) && $page_now != 0){
      return true;
}else{
    return false;
}
```

Comment: I would suggest expanding on why they should try this. Give an explanation of the code and why you think it would work for the user http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/196187/is-try-this-bad-practice

Comment: i tried empty & isset both are not work, i want my code stop process if it return ""

Comment: it's edited now, still pretty new to stackOverflow :)